# ReactJS Why can't I modify children passed into a component

Tags: reactjs

I figured I could do this, but I am getting this error:

TypeError: child.constructor.ConvenienceConstructor is not a function

I have a component in a page, ala:

// this content is in an html page. My component reads in this child, but I can't seem to modify any part of it.. Just diplay it.

```
<MyComponent prop1="somevalue">
   <div className="myclass1"> some child content that is dynamic </div>
</MyComponent>
```

Now, in my component since that inner child(ren) is dynamic, I need to change that class depending on some condition. But I can't. I get that error I noted above.

I tried this:

```
var childContent = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
    function(child) {
            return React.cloneWithProps(child,
                { className: 'myNEWClass' } );
    });
```

I tried **cloneElement** too, that didn't work either.

Doesn't work. I tried accessing the child directly, ala:

```
 child._store.props.className // but can't seem to change it, seems immutable.
```

So, how can I change that class up?

thanks,

Comment: would [React.cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) work in your context?

Comment: should of mentioned it. I did try that, no dice. thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What version of React do you use? `cloneElement` in 0.13.1 works exactly as you want it to when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

Props are supposed to be immutable, so instead of passing className as a prop, you make the parent pass in a prop named defaultClass. In your map method, you can add an extra prop, say, overrideClass. Finally, in the render() method of the actual child component, you need some logic to set the className to either overrideClass, or defaultClass. In this way, you don't have to mutate props.